# DropDownList in MVC not working in IE8

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-8

In my Code in .cshtml

```
<span class="float-left">
@Html.DropDownList("searchOption", actions, "--Select Category--")
</span>
```

in Css file

```
.float-left {

    float: left;
}
```

it's working fine in IE9

[image]

in IE8 text is not proper

[image]

can Any one say what i need to do for this

Comment: fiddle with css included?

Answer (score 0):

in your 'float-left' add this,

```
.float-left {
position:relative;
z-index:1000;
   float: left;
}
```